# Rails Query Joins and Where Not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have two models, Customer and Driver.
There is a join table (as a full model) which is used to blacklist drivers and customers from each other.

```
class Driver
  has_many :customer_blacklists
  has_many :blacklisted_customers, through: :customer_blacklists, source: :customer
end


class Customer
  has_many :driver_blacklists, class_name: 'CustomerBlacklist', foreign_key: 'customer_id'
  has_many :blacklisted_drivers, through: :driver_blacklists, source: :driver
end

class CustomerBlacklist
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

I want to create an *efficient* query to find all drivers who are not blacklisted by the current customer.

Currently I have either:

```
Driver.where.not(id: CustomerBlacklist.where(customer_id: customer_id).pluck(:driver_id))
```

or

```
Driver.where.not(id: [customer.blacklisted_drivers.pluck(:id)] ) }
```

Both of these work fine (they're basically the same thing, the second is more readable.
But there are two seperate queries happening here.

I've tried without success to make this a single query, my last try looked like:

```
Driver.left_joins(:customer_blacklists).where.not(customer_blacklists: {driver_id: driver_id, customer_id: customer_id} )
```

But this returns only Drivers who *do* have an entry in the `customers_blacklists` table, but not for the specified customer.
It does not include any drivers who have never been blacklisted at all.

The query should return

- All Drivers who are not blacklisted by anyone
- All Drivers who are not blacklisted by the current customer

Comment: you can use `select` instead of `pluck` to get the result in single query `Driver.where.not(id: [customer.blacklisted_drivers.select(:id)] ) }`

Comment: @SampatBadhe you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you actually need is:

```
Driver.where.not(id: customer.blacklisted_drivers)
```

ActiveRecord is smart enough to build a subquery when you pass an assocation to `.where`. `.pluck(:id)` is largely an anti-pattern as you're preventing the ORM from actually making a better query.

Another alternative to a subquery that can be more performant is a [lateral join](https://sambleckley.com/writing/lateral-in-rails.html) - however there is no polyglot solution for that so it would be database specific. I would revisit this later if the performance actually becomes a problem.